# How to do programmatic navigation in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react js. And I bumped into this problem. When I click the login button I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

   let history = useHistory();

   const handleclick = () => {
       history.push("/dashboard");
   }

   return (
       <Button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mt-2" onClick={ handleclick }> Login </Button>
   )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your <App/> component with `BrowserRouter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing  tag in your index.js component.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: How could you even know that when he didn't provide that file?

Comment: @radovix its easy to know if you have done the same mistake :)